# Create notifications from PhoneStateListener

Tags: android, android-notifications, phone-state-listener

I am working on Android app and I have receive a broadcast for incoming calls and I need to create a notification in the notification tray.

I am trying the following

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)this;
```

But this displays an error `Cannot cast from PhoneStateManager to NotificationManager`.

I've also tried using `context` instead of `this` but then says it can't cast from `PhoneStateManager` to `NotificationManager`.

How can I create the notification from the PhoneStateListener, is this possible or do I need to pass it to a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get an instance of it [like the docs say](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html):

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Since you didn't post more code, it's hard to tell what you can use for `context`. If you do have a `Context` variable, use it. If your listener is contained in an Activity/Service do `MyActivity.this` or `MyService.this` instead of the `context` variable that I used in my code snippet.